# Sqlalchemy filter by date

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to construct a query that filters a list of hotel rates. I only want to  show hotel reservations from today and into the future. The query I built is below but does not filter the results. What am I doing wrong?

```
hotels = db.session.query(Hotel).\
    join(Location).\
    join(Rate).\
    filter(Location.city == city).\
    filter(Rate.arrive > datetime.utcnow())
```

For background, my models look like this:

```
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)

    hotels = relationship('Hotel', back_populates='location')


class Hotel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hotels'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    phone_number = Column(String(20))
    parking_fee = Column(String(10))
    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('locations.id'), nullable=False)

    location = relationship('Location', back_populates='hotels')
    rates = relationship('Rate', back_populates='hotel', order_by='Rate.arrive')


class Rate(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rates'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    price = Column(Numeric(6, 2))
    arrive = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    link = Column(String(500), nullable=False)
    updated = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    hotel_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hotels.id'), nullable=False)

    hotel = relationship('Hotel', back_populates='rates')
```

Edit:
Here is some sample data:

```
Date: Friday, Sep 9

Rate: 299.25

Date: Sunday, Sep 11

Rate: 261.75

Date: Monday, Sep 12

Rate: 261.75

Date: Tuesday, Sep 13

Rate: 261.75

Date: Sunday, Sep 18
```

Removing filter(Rate.arrive > datetime.utcnow()) does not change the data. It is output the same each time I run the query.

Comment: What results do you get when you execute the query? Is it the same when you remove `filter(Rate.arrive > datetime.utcnow()`? Or is the result empty? *BTW, sample data and expected query results would be of help.*

Comment: I added some sample data. All of the results are displayed when the filter is in place and also when it is removed.

Comment: Your query returns `Hotel` instance, and the logic of your query is: *return hotels in the city of interest where **there is at least one** Rate after some date*. Therefore, if there is *at least one* `Rate` after the `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`, the hotel will be returned. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Van that it is the crux of my problem. I want to return a Hotel instance, and for each set of Rates only return Rates that are after date time.utcnow(). I've seen that the query is acting like you said but am not sure how to get it where I want.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, will post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Option zero is to apply the filter of rates after you loaded the hotels, but this will generate additional queries, and is not desired.*

Define filters which are used later on:

```
city = 'mumbai'
arrive = datetime.date.today()
```

**Option-1: Load `Rate` of interest in the initial query**

```
query = (
    session.query(Hotel, Rate)  # this query will return pairs (Hotel, Rate)
    .join(Location)
    .join(Rate)
    .filter(Location.city == city)
    .filter(Rate.arrive > arrive)
)

# one could use the results directly as (Hotel, Rate) pairs
# but we can also convert to the format: {hotel: rates}
from collections import defaultdict
hotels_list = defaultdict(list)
for h, r in hotels:
    hotels_list[h].append(r)

# and print:
for hotel, rates in hotels_list.items():
    print('', hotel)
    for rate in rates:
        print('  ', rate)
```

**Option-2: *Trick* the relationship `Hotel.rates`**

Here we are using [contains_eager](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager)

```
hotels = (
    session.query(Hotel)
    .join(Location)
    .join(Rate)
    .options(contains_eager(Hotel.rates))  # this is the key
    .filter(Location.city == city)
    .filter(Rate.arrive > arrive)
)


for hotel in hotels:
    print('', hotel)
    for rate in hotel.rates:  # this now contains only sub-list, so be careful
        print('  ', rate)
```

Comment: Hallelujah thank you! I used the contains_eager method and it worked great. Now I just need to read the docs more so I can fully understand what's going on.

Comment: By using `contains_eager` you basically *trick* the `sqlalchemy` to think that it loaded *all* the relationship. Therefore you should be careful with using it. But the usage is quite elegant, and I do it from time to time.